# Remove self as delegate from all

Tags: objective-c, delegates

There's a way to remove self as observer from all notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Is there a similar way to remove `self` as a delegate of all objects that the `viewController` is a delegate of?

I want to place it in `dealloc` method in my prototype `viewController`. The reason is that sometimes when I dismiss a `viewController`, I get a crash with a message that a `UIScrollView` (or any of the official subclasses) called a method on its delegate (the `viewController`) that has since been deallocated. Since I consciously intend to call no such methods, I'd rather set `self.delegate = nil`. But since this is a prototype `viewController`, I don't have outlets to those scrollViews, hence my question.

Comment: Is your delegate declared as `weak`? For instance: `@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomeDelegateProtocol> delegate`? Or is it `(nonatomic, strong)` or `(nonatomic, retain)`?

Comment: Or you don't control the code that declares a delegate (it is a third-party or Apple code)?

Comment: It's the latter - I'm declaring `self` as a delegate of `UIScrollView`, `UITableView`, etc.

Comment: This is what weak references are for in the modern run-time, they zero out deallocated object references, which stops this kind of crash.

Comment: I have run into this crash before.  The best suggestion I can give is to create an outlet to your scrollView (most likely a tableView) and in dealloc set `self.tableView.delegate = nil`

Comment: I updated my answer. My answer attempts to solve the problem in a general case, but if all objects that use your ViewController as their delegate, belong to your ViewController's view hierarchy, @Logan's solution is simpler and more elegant.

Comment: I'm curious how you've run into this problem assuming you're on ARC. If not, i.e. you have no 'weak' references, then it is lifetime design that is probably broken. The real problem is why your VC is deallocated while it's view is /still on-screen/. And please show @interfaces at least.

Comment: I am on ARC. I'm assigning `self` as `delegate` via Interface Builder, and I'm dismissing `self` either with `dismissViewController` or `popViewController`. Since I'm using all stock techniques, I can only assume the funny behaviour comes from Apple's side of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing this code in my superclass' `dealloc` method solved my crashes:

```
for (id view in self.view.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

        [view setDelegate:nil];
    }
}
```

I was considering doing this in my `viewController`  where I have direct access to the `UIScrollView`. However, because ARC disallows calling `[super dealloc]`, this does not allow the `dealloc` code in my superclass to be called.

Comment: You can override dealloc safely. The super method will also be called, but ARC will do it for you.

Comment: You're right, I just tested it. It's not explicit though, so the code is less readable.. But it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such way. Once we are done with the delegate, it requires to simply `nil` that reference.

Also before calling any delegate method make sure, to check nil condition as well method availability condition like:

```
if (_delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateMethod:)]) {

   // then only call that delegate method
   [self.delegate myDelegateMethod:param];
}
```

Once you are done with all your delegate things `nil` your reference:

`self.delegate = nil;`

Comment: Actually, if `myDelegateMethod` doesn't return anything, the check is not required. `[self.delegate]` will return `nil`, calling `[self.delegate myDelegateMethod:param]` will also simply return `nil` or `0`. If it returns something meaningful, just keep in mind, that it might return `nil`/`0`, if the delegate is not set, and handle this situation if required.

Comment: Check is required, if self.delegate has been released from memory, then it will not respond to delegateMethod and it will throw runtime error (Method not found). Hence this check is better always. And when we are done with delegate functionality, simply nil it, self.delegate = nil;

Comment: Now, it's not required. Because this is one of reasons why "delegates should never be retained" rule exists. If a delegate is weak-referenced, it will be automatically set to `nil` when it is deallocated. And when it's `nil`, we can send it any message we want, it will respond with `nil` or `0` as I said previously. So the only way a problem that you describe can occur is when delegate is strong-referenced.

Comment: Of course, the main reason for "never retain" rule is retain cycles avoidance, but an ability to get rid of thousands of `if (nil == self.delegate)` checks is a nice benefit.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes you cannot check if the `delegate` responds to a selector - for instance, when the call is made by Apple's framework classes - see my question edit for an example.

Comment: Nil check is pointless. If _delegate is nil, then -[respondsToSelector:] and -[myDelegateMethod:] are just no-ops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any built-in mechanism for it. I think, that the code that was responsible for making your object a delegate should be responsible for freeing it of this responsibility. You could provide some interface for it, but it depends on your code.

Also, since delegates are weak-referenced, they will be automatically set to nil when the delegate object is deleted, but it's not your case, I believe.

**UPDATE:**

Since in your case delegates don't seem to be declared as weak, I guess, the only option is to keep track of all objects that set your viewController as their delegate manually.

For instance:

In your ViewController:

```
@interface YourViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *objectsThatDelegateSomethingToUs;
@end

@implementation YourViewController

-(void)makeDelegateOfObject:(id)obj withDelegatePropertyName:(NSString*)delegatePropertyName {
    [self.objectsThatDelegateSomethingToUs setObject:delegatePropertyName forKey:obj];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    for (id obj in self.objectsThatDelegateSomethingToUs.allKeys) {
        [obj setValue:nil forKey:[self.objectsThatDelegateSomethingToUs valueForKey:obj]];
    }
}

@end
```

Where you set your viewController as a delegate:

```
scrollView.delegate = viewController;
[viewController makeDelegateOfObject:scrollView withDelegatePropertyName:@"delegate"];
```

But, sadly, in this case you'll have to set your ViewController as a delegate programmatically. If delegate property is always called `delegate`, NSMutableArray should do the trick.

Actually, it's weird that scrollView keeps working when it's parent ViewController is deallocated. May be this is the real problem, and it can be fixed somehow, but, unfortunately, I can't give you any advice on it now, so my answer is trying to deal with the problem that you originally asked about. I recommend you to leave the question open for a while, may be someone else will be able to suggest a better solution.

P.S. Check out Logan's comment to your question. If all objects that use your ViewController as their delegate, are parts of ViewControllers' view hierarchy, then his solution is simpler and more elegant.

Comment: Not all delegates are weak-referenced, or don't seem to be, particularly for scroll views, as the questioner is seeing. It's a long-standing problem in UIKit.

Comment: @jrturton, oh, I see. Well, that's not good. It shouldn't be this way as far I know, but whatever. Then, I guess, the only option is to track all objects that have set us as their delegate and set their delegates to `nil` manually. I will update my answer now.

Comment: It's a bug, I think. It only seems to turn up occasionally if you do things like go to another view controller while the scroll view is scrolling.

Comment: @jrturton, in my case it happens when I have a `UITextField` which `isFirstResponder` and I dismiss the `viewController`. I assume that what happens in the deallocation process is that first `self.view.editing` is set to `NO`, which in turn triggers my method for scrolling my `scrollView` (part of making sure the keyboard doesn't obscure my views). But, by that time the `viewController` had been deallocated. So, as FreeNickname has suggested, I will probably have to set `self.delegate = nil` manually before dismissing `self`